SQL one to many join table issue
I have 2 tables which is one to many relationship.  I want to join both table but the result shown after join is not what I need.  Below is the table and sample data.
Create table #temp (
    DONo varchar(10),
    Amount decimal(18,2),
    OrderNo varchar(10)
)

Create table #order (
    Item varchar(10),
    Amount decimal(18,2),
    OrderNo varchar(10),
    PackingDate date
)

Insert into #temp(DONo, Amount, OrderNo)
VALUES('A123', 1000, 'O123')
Insert into #temp(DONo, Amount, OrderNo)
VALUES('A124', 1100, 'O124')

Insert into #order (OrderNo, Item, Amount, PackingDate)
VALUES('O123', 'Pen', 100, '2024-02-01')
Insert into #order (OrderNo, Item, Amount, PackingDate)
VALUES ('O123', 'Color', 800, '2024-02-01')
Insert into #order (OrderNo, Item, Amount, PackingDate)
VALUES ('O123', 'Box', 100, '2024-02-02')

I have try below join query
select 
   do.DONo, do. Amount, do.OrderNo, SUM(so.Amount)[[OrderAmount], so.PackingDate 
from #temp do
left join
  #order so
on
  do.OrderNo = so.OrderNo
group by
  do.DONo, do. Amount, do.OrderNo, so.PackingDate

Here is the output for above query
DONo    DOAmount  OrderNo   Amount     PackingDate
A123    1000.00   O123     900.00     2024-02-01
A123    1000.00   O123     100.00     2024-02-02
A124    1100.00   O124      NULL      NULL

The expected output I wish as below
DONo    DOAmount  OrderNo   Amount     PackingDate
A123    1000.00   O123     900.00     2024-02-01
A123              O123     100.00     2024-02-02
A124    1100.00   O124      NULL      NULL

Since the DO no is same for order O123, the amount for DO I need shown once.  The reason why I need show the DO amount once is because when in the visualization, the tools will sum up the DO amount and it will become double up in the bar chart.
I think my direction is wrong and my table design was wrong.  Please guide me how I can fixed it and show the result I need.

What does the blank represent? It's not NULL as you are explicit with NULL values, but it also can't be a zero length string, as DOAmount is clearly a numerical type. Though, seems like you just need to check the value of the ROW_NUMBER and change the value when it's not 1.

Does this answer your question? How to get first row value from each group and apply to first record only, rest will be 0 or null in SQL Server

This sounds like an X/Y problem. "because when in the visualization, the tools will sum up the DO amount" - Can you change them to not do it? Instead of summation may be they can do something else e.g. pick largest? What tools are you using?

@ThomA, thanks for guiding me to the direction.  It's work now.

just replace
do.Amount,

by this
 case when row_number() over (partition by do.DONo order by do.DONo) = 1 then do.Amount else null end as Amount,

full query
select do.DONo, 
       case when row_number() over (partition by do.DONo order by do.DONo) = 1 then do.Amount else null end as Amount,
       do.OrderNo, 
       sum(so.Amount)OrderAmount, 
       so.PackingDate 
from temp do
  left join orders so on do.OrderNo = so.OrderNo
group by
  do.DONo, do. Amount, do.OrderNo, so.PackingDate

result



DONo
Amount
OrderNo
OrderAmount
PackingDate




A123
1000.00
O123
900.00
2024-02-01


A123
null
O123
100.00
2024-02-02


A124
1100.00
O124
null
null



See this demo

Your design is fine and your current result is perfectly valid.
This isn't a problem with SQL but with the visualization tool you're using.
However, if you can't find a way for the visualization tool to ignore multiple values for the same DONo, there's still a way to do handle it in pure T-SQL, by using RowNumber and a common table expression:
;WITH CTE AS 
(
select 
   do.DONo, do.Amount, do.OrderNo, SUM(so.Amount)[OrderAmount], so.PackingDate, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY do.DONo ORDER BY so.PackingDate) As RN
from #temp do
left join
  #order so
on
  do.OrderNo = so.OrderNo
group by
  do.DONo, do. Amount, do.OrderNo, so.PackingDate
)

SELECT DONo, IIF(RN = 1, Amount, NULL) As Amount, OrderNo, OrderAmount, PackingDate
FROM CTE
ORDER BY DONo, PackingDate;

Note: The semicolon (;) char is a terminator char.
It doesn't actually belong before the WITH keyword, however since it's generally optional in T-SQL (unless the next statement is a common table expression), it's common practice to start common table expressions with a semicolon before the WITH keyword.

I don't think an CTE is even needed here, see this demo

@GuidoG I agree, that's better. want to publish as an answer, or to edit that in this one?

I wrote it in an answer
